# Oracle Apex - Display Item as a Percentage

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to show a text field item as a percentage, issue is that there are several queries depending on this item (it refreshes reports based on the value).

Right now I have decimal values in there (1 = 100% , 0.5 = 50% and so on).

But the customer is asking to show this item as a percentage (50% when I have 0.5).

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

PS: The #col_name#% approach doesn't work well for this case.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to have the a 2nd item.

- Suppose the base item is `P1_COMMISSION` and that is the value stored in the database - I suppose that would be a value between 0 and 1. Create another item called `P1_COMMISSION_PCT` which is displays the percent value. If this is a form item, this item would *not* have a database columns as source.
- Make `P1_COMMISSION` hidden
- Add a computation after the form initialisation to calculate the `P1_COMMISSION_PCT` based on `P1_COMMISSION`
- Add a dynamic action on change of `P1_COMMISSION_PCT` to recalculate the value of `P1_COMMISSION`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to

- set current item to be **hidden** (so that you wouldn't see 1 or 0.5 as its values, but other objects would still be able to use it) and
- create a new, display only item, whose source would be current item, but properly formatted, e.g.

  ```
  TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(:P1_COL_NAME) * 100) || '%'
  ```